# How to list approvers of pull request from AWS CodeCommit

Tags: amazon-web-services, pull-request, aws-codecommit

From AWS CodeCommit, we can view the list of pull requests.  However, it seems that we cannot display an "approver" column in the table.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/how-to-view-pull-request.html

How could I generate a report of pull requests with its approver(s)?

[image: Pull Requests]

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no such an option. But you can achieve that by first getting the list of open pull requests like this:

```
aws codecommit list-pull-requests --pull-request-status OPEN --repository-name <REPO_NAME>
```

Then iterate over those pull request and run the following command to get the revision id:

```
aws codecommit get-pull-request \
--pull-request-id <PR_ID>
```

Once you have that information you can get the approvers like this:

```
aws codecommit get-pull-request-approval-states \
--pull-request-id <PR_ID> \
--revision-id <REVIONSION_ID>
```

I know, it shouldn't be that complicated.